# Fluent Nhibernate table-per-subclass with discriminator strategy

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there anyway to use fluent in order to implement the *table-per-subclass with discriminator* strategy?  From all of the documentation I've seen, the use of a discriminator actually tells fluent to use the *table-per-class* rather than *table-per-subclass*.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue.  So far the only option i have been able to think of is to put a property on the base class and have its set operation protected.  Then any class that inherits the base, sets that property in its constructor.  So far i have not found a better way.

in my case i have a class that references the base class and i want to query the type of subclass in that reference and filter on it in a  query but found no way apart from what i just suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 table for each subclass then isn't the discriminator the name of the table...  In other words you don't need to specify a discriminator if there is only 1 type per table.

Comment: The ORM may not need the column, but for convenience I would like an automatic 'discriminator' column in the table so I can restrict my query to only a certain subclass type.

Also, what I'm looking for is a [supported strategy](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-8-inheritance-mapping#8(2E)1(2E)3(2E)(C2)(A0)Table_per_subclass(2C)_using_a_discriminator) in NHibernate, but I just don't see how to do it in fluent.